# Suspect crawler without citing source

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service, reporting

This question from this site seems to be a SO question:

[image]

Unfortunately, it is all translated to my language so I couldn't search for the origin question. All the users are changed to Vietnamese names completely. I mean completely native Vietnamese names, not just the translated names.

I just want to report this.

https://helpex.vn/question/chat-luong-hinh-anh-xau-sau-khi-thay-doi-kich-thuoc--ty-le-bitmap-5cd00dfeae03f632bc16287d

Comment: Here’s the original: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821488/6083675